# How to page redirect for Membership area - php

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, membership

I'm trying to redirect users upon login, to a specific page based on their membership level. I have tried the code below but it seems to redirect the users only to the '/membership-account' and ignores all my conditions.

Can anyone offer any advice, please?

Thanks in advance.

```
function login_redirect_page() {
    //get current user membership level
    global $current_user;
    $current_user->membership_level = pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($current_user->ID);

    //this is a conditional statement that checks the membership level ID and redirects to the right page. Repeat for all levels.
    if( 4 ===   $current_user->membership_level->id ){
        return '/mixfit/';
    }

    if($current_user->membership_level->ID === 1){
        return '/hiit/';
    }

    if( 2 ===   $current_user->membership_level->id ){
        return '/hiit/';
    }

    if( 3 ===   $current_user->membership_level->id ){
        return '/stretch-and-flex/';
    }

    if( 5 ===   $current_user->membership_level->id ){
        return '/pilates/';
    }

    return '/membership-account/';
}
add_filter('login_redirect', 'login_redirect_page');
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Presumably `$current_user->membership_level->id` never matches any of your values. But we have no idea how you are populating that variable or what data it contains. You need to debug it yourself - we can't run your code or see your data. Add some simple logging to see what happens, or use XDebug.

Comment: Have you tried to use `==` instead of `===`? If the id isn't an integer then you may end up with failed compares

Comment: I also noticed this: `$current_user->membership_level = pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($current_user->ID);`... Is the `->membership_level` an object? Because, in your if-statements you use `->membership_level->id`. Is `id` a member of `membership_level`?

Comment: Oh and once you use `ID` instead of `id` too. PHP is case-sensitive. Attention to detail please...

Comment: hahaha sorry @ADyson, I'm very new to php!

Comment: @Gowire I've tried `==` instead of `===` and it still produces the same outcome. I also tried to change `pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($current_user->ID)` to `pmpro_getMembershipLevelForUser($current_user->->membership_level->ID)` but this didnt work either?

Comment: You seem to still be guessing. Do some actual debugging. Check the actual values being used in your code when you run it.